# how can I write complex queries in eloquent Orm?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
SELECT * FROM user_fields WHERE (SELECT CITY FROM register_expert WHERE PERMISSION=1 AND ID=user_fields.ID_USER_FIELD)='$city_save'AND TITLE_USER_FIELD='$text_search_service';
```

Here is `register_expert` table [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PS5S.png)

And here is `user_fields` table [mage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDvpt.png)

Comment: Did you define any relationship? if yes then show us

Comment: Are you using models?

Comment: no I don't write any relationship yet, But I can define relationship @bhavinjr

Comment: @thisiskelvin no

Comment: You first will need to define models and relationships before being able to use eloquent (orm) queries

Comment: I don't think your database and/or your query is not really well designed, because the fact that you need to query to the register_expert table the city and you try to check with user with the city name but you don't have cities column to check to. If that where the case that would need that each user should have a column for each country which is a many-to-many relationships and cities must be in an specific table and then you would need to create relationships in the specific models.

Answer (score 0):

Assuuming, 
 `userFields` is your models.

```
userFields::selectRaw("user_fields.ID_USER_FIELD")
            ->join('register_expert', function($join) use ($city_save){
                $join->on('register_expert.id', 'user_fields.ID_USER_FIELD')
                    ->where('PERMISSION', '1')
                    ->where('city', $city_save)
            })->where('TITLE_USER_FIELD', $text_search_service);
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Eloquent query should look something like this but as I said in my comment the database and query is not well designed so I don't think it will work but just so you have an idea of how to make more complex queries in Eloquent.

```
$registerExperts = RegisterExperts::whereColumn('ID_USER_FIELD', 'user_fields.ID')
    ->Andwhere('PERMISSION', '=', 1)
    ->limit(1)
    ->select('city')
    ->get();

$users = User::where($registerExperts->get('city') , '=', $city_save)
->andWhere('TITLE_USER_FIELD', '=', $text_search_service)
->get();
```

And here's a good first article to see how to make complex queries using Eloquent ORM : [Dynamic relationships in Laravel using subqueries by Jonathan Reinink](https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries)

Comment: In lin one,when I use whereColumn statement, I see this error:

 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''user_fields.ID_USER_FIELD'' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `city` from `register_experts` where `ID` = `'user_fields`.`ID_USER_FIELD'` and `PERMISSION` = 1)
unable to Identify `'user_fields`.`ID_USER_FIELD'`

Comment: I'm not sure but I think those fields where exchanged and must be the other way `whereColumn('ID_USER_FIELD', 'user_fields.ID')`. I edited the post to correct this.